# How to cast a std::stringbuf into an array of char?

Tags: c++, string, c-str

What I'm trying to do here is to cast a `stringbuf` object into an array of char.

I do this to send the array of char to a `C` interface which doesn't understand the type `std::stringbuf`.

Here's a part of my code to illustrate the problem :

```
std::stringbuf buffer;
char * data;

//here i fill my buffer with an object
buffer >> Myobject;
//here is the function I want to create but I don't know if it's possible
data = convertToCharArray(buffer);
//here I send my buffer of char to my C interface
sendToCInterface(data);
```

Comment: it seems to work but how do i use this method ?

Comment: look @bobah 's answer, he even tackle ownership issue

Comment: @Kiroxas oh, only now I see you responded the same as a comment. So I'll add a ref.

Comment: `//here i fill my buffer with an object` this seems not to be the case with `buffer >> Myobject;`. Did you probably mix up the operator direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Kiroxas* suggests in [the first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867728/how-to-cast-a-stdstringbuf-into-a-array-of-char#comment36737257_23867728), try to avoid intermediate variables:

```
sendToCInterface(buffer.str().c_str());
```

*...the less variables the less confusion ;-)*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a strict zero-copy/high performance requirement then:

```
std::string tmp = buffer.str();

// call C-interface, it is expected to not save the pointer
sendToCharInterface(tmp.data(), tmp.size()); 

// call C-interface giving it unique dynamically allocated copy, note strdup(...)
sendToCharInterface(strndup(tmp.data(), tmp.size()), tmp.size());
```

If you do need it to be fast (yet still have stringbuf on the way) then you can look in the direction of [stringbuf::pubsetbuf()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to convert a std::stringbuf  into a char pointer, I think you could just do

```
std::string bufstring = buffer.str();
```

to get a string, and convert this into a c-style string using

```
bufstring.c_str()
```

to pass a character pointer to a function